# UIView clipsToBounds doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I have a view controller with XIB, with a view (`contentView`) inside. This view contains some buttons.

The content view has round corners and clips to bounds, but it doesn't respect the clipping rect. I set the corner radius and the `clipsToBounds` in the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller.

Here you can see the reveal screenshot that shows that the view is composed in the correct way, but on simulator and device clipping bounds are not respected.

Anybody can please help me to understand what happen.

The app is targeted to iOS 10 and 11, and both have the same issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the code you use particularly in viewDidLoad which your reference.  Without that how can we tell if it is being set incorrectly.

Comment: it's xcode ?? which tool you can use??

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth i post the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, I move the clipsToBound in the viewDidLayoutSubviews instead viewDidLoad and now works

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = Dimensions.CornerRaius
    contentView.dropShadow()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Where was the `contentView.clipsToBounds = true` originally before you moved it.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I defined my view (UIView in my case) like that:

```
fileprivate let backView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

The image:

```
fileprivate let imgView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()
```

In my case I defined these elements in a custom table view cell:

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {
```

Although I set **"clipsToBounds = true"** in the definition of background view, not clip the image.

But, if I set **"clipsToBounds = true"** later, it clips the image.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    backView.addSubview(imgView)
    contentView.addSubview(backView)

    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4).isActive = true

    backView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    backView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    backView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    backView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And inside **"init"** method:

```
backView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: adding a .clipToBounds method to the init really helps!