# How to clip the multiple image based on parent view bounds in xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have multiple image view to be positioned in the main view. While scaling the view, the image view goes out of the frame. I have checked by enabling ClipToBounds property but does not work.How to clip the images when exceed its parent frame in xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Which method do you enable `ClipToBounds` inside ? Try to move the code form `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` , details refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48033473/8187800).

Comment: Initially I have enabled ClipToBounds in the constructor. But now, I have that by using that in LayoutSubview() and now also, it not works. Also, I need to mention that I have set separate frame for the image views added in the main view and not using the parent view's frame